# If I am not using a stencil for my PCB, do I need to use the solder paste (.gtp) tCream layer?

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

Or is the paste layer always needed? I do have SMD components.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you plan to assemble the board.

Some PCB manufacturers offer to make you a (free?) stencil but if you manually solder your board yourself you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

The paste layer is used for assembly, if a manufacturer wants to put paste on the board then they will need a file to tell them where. It is also useful for those wanting to generate a mask for applying paste.

If your only doing a copper board only the top and bottom and drill files are needed. (if your manufacturer will do that)

If you want silkscreen and soldermask then you also provide the files for those.

Comment: And another for outline is usually a good idea. So, 7 files for a 2-layer board plus drill file(s). Maybe one of the latter for both plated and unplated holes plus another for slots.

Comment: Forgot about the drill filles, editing. I've actually manufactured my own PCB's with a double sided board on a CNC machine, which is an exercise I'd recommend for anyone

Comment: Nice that the CAM software (even windows based) is free for that. Not my cup of tea to do regularly, but I've tried it once on a CNC engraver with V-bit.

Comment: Not my cup of tea either, I've realized that the maker revolution is a sham and a waste of time. I bought a CNC table, after the 40 hours of getting everything to work right, I made 2 pcbs and then I realized what a colossal waste of time it is and I could have bought 30 pcb's for the cost of the table and software. With anything (PCB's, machining) it's faster and cheaper to leave it to the experts. It is *some fun* building them yourself just to cut your teeth on it.